# HTTP timeout exception occurring when trying to renew ADAL access token on a different threads

Tags: c#, http, azure, oauth, adal

I'm having a very difficult to debug problem having to do with ADAL renewing access tokens on different threads. My situation is that I'm trying to use the ADAL library to get an access token for an AD application to connect to a SQL Azure database. I'm acquiring the token inside of an autofac registration so that every time someone asks for it, it re-executes (authContext is a static AuthenticationContext property)

```
authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/", certCred).Result;
```

I believe this is causing problems because the following steps result in the access token request timing out -

1). Start the application, request an access token in thread #1. Success

2). Increase my computer's time by one day, request an access token again in thread #1. The old token is deleted and the library attempts to acquire another token. Success

3). Increase my computer's time by one day, request an access token again in thread #2. This time the token is deleted and it tries to get another token by sending a request. Unfortunately the request ends up timing out after 30 seconds.

Interestingly, if I inspect the requests in Charles or Fiddler the request in #2 looks fine - it's a POST to the correct endpoint. #3 results in a CONNECT request to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" with no relevant headers or body content. I've looked at the requests in the debugger and #3 seems to be created just like the request in #2.

I haven't been able to reproduce it in a smaller project unfortunately. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What version of ADAL?

Comment: Version 3.13.2 - https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/releases/tag/v3.13.2

Comment: Can you share the exception thrown?

Comment: Turns out this is a problem with the way I'm using async/await, not a problem with the ADAL library. I'll close and create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a problem with the way I'm using async/await, not a problem with the ADAL library. I'll close and create a new question.